# How to make key:array map from array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dictionary

I've been struggling making key, values map, any thoughts how could I do that? I have array from SQL like this:

| id | categoryId | name | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | table | ... |
| 2 | 55 | chair | ... |
| 3 | 47 | PC | ... |
| 4 | 44 | TV | ... |
| 5 | 47 | phone | ... |

How can I make categoryId: ['Id's] key, values map? It should look like this:

```
{
   '55': [1, 2],
   '47': [3,5],
   '44': [4]
}
```

This is what I tried, is there any better way?

```
// products
// [
//    {id: 1, categoryId: 55, name: 'table'},
//    {id: 2, categoryId: 55, name: 'chair'},
//    {id: 3, categoryId: 47, name: 'PC'},
//    {id: 4, categoryId: 44, name: 'TV'},
//    {id: 5, categoryId: 47, name: 'phone'},
// ]

const products = await this.repository.getData(data, { statuses: statuses } );
        const productsMap = {};
        products.forEach(product => {
            if (!productsMap[product.categoryId]) {
                productsMap[product.categoryId] = products.filter(a => a.categoryId == product.categoryId);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Needs more details and what you have done to solve this problem?

Comment: Added what I tried

Comment: Please edit the question to show your input structure. Otherwise we're just guessing.  Here's one guess: `Object.fromEntries([... new Set(products.map(p => p.categoryId))] .map(ci => [ci, products.filter(({categoryId: id}) => id == ci).map(p => p.id)]))`

Comment: This is a server side question, you should tag the server side language that you're using and also show what you've tried. Given that this question is two days old you're going to get very little if any attention as most traffic is within the first few hours of posting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Map`.

```
const products = await this.repository.getData(data, { statuses: statuses } );

const productsMap = new Map();
for (const product of products) {
    if (productsMap.has(product.categoryId)) {
        productsMap.get(product.categoryId).push(product.id);
    } else {
        productsMap.set(product.categoryId, [product.id]);
    }
}

console.log(productsMap);
// Map { 55 => [ 1, 2 ], 47 => [ 3, 5 ], 44 => [ 4 ] }

console.log(productsMap.get(55)); // [ 1, 2 ]
console.log(productsMap.get(44)); // [ 4 ]
console.log(productsMap.get(400)); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem like this can be quite simple when you have a collection of useful helper functions available.  This is what I first wrote, with the [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com) library at hand (disclaimer: I'm one of Ramda's founders):

```js
const categorize = pipe (
  groupBy (prop ('categoryId')), 
  map (pluck ('id'))
)

const products = [ {id: 1, categoryId: 55, name: 'table'}, {id: 2, categoryId: 55, name: 'chair'}, {id: 3, categoryId: 47, name: 'PC'}, {id: 4, categoryId: 44, name: 'TV'}, {id: 5, categoryId: 47, name: 'phone'},]

console .log (categorize (products))
```

```html
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, groupBy, prop, map, pluck} = R                            </script>
```

But these helper functions are often simple enough that we don't need a library to include them.  A personal collection of snippets works great.  We could use the same code by including a few helpers:

```js
const pipe = (...fns) => (arg) => fns .reduce ((a, f) => f (a), arg)
const prop = (name) => (obj) => obj [name]
const map = (fn) => (o) => Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => [k, fn(v)]))
const pluck = (name) => (xs) => xs .map (x => x [name])
const groupBy = (fn) => (xs) => xs .reduce ((a, x) => ({... a, [fn (x)]: [... (a [fn (x)] || []), x]}), {})

const categorize = pipe (
  groupBy (prop ('categoryId')), 
  map (pluck ('id'))
)

const products = [ {id: 1, categoryId: 55, name: 'table'}, {id: 2, categoryId: 55, name: 'chair'}, {id: 3, categoryId: 47, name: 'PC'}, {id: 4, categoryId: 44, name: 'TV'}, {id: 5, categoryId: 47, name: 'phone'},]

console .log (categorize (products))
```

Ramda's versions of these functions are generally more sophisticated than the above.  But these do for our purposes here, and, except for `map`, are very broadly useful.  For `map`, a more useful version than this one would work on objects or arrays, perhaps with code like this:

```js
const mapArray = (fn) => (xs) => xs .map (x => fn (x)) 
const mapObj = (fn) => (o) => Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => [k, fn(v)]))
const map = (fn) => (t) => (Array .isArray (t) ? mapArray : mapObj) (fn) (t)
```

and with that, we might choose to rewrite `pluck` like this.

```js
const pluck = name => map (prop (name))
```

But this is not essential.  Such simple helper functions can make many tasks much easier.